# C# proxy server for http

Tags: c#, proxy

I want to write a simple http proxy server in C#. My proxy server is already able to get requests from the client and forward them to the host. It should also be already able to forward Responses from the host to the client. However, not all requests and responses are sent correctly. I want to open simple http websites with it, but it doesn't work right now. I think the problem is that I can't just forward the requests and responses directly. Do I need to adjust them before forwarding them? Or is there a different error? Thanks in advance!

```
public class ProxyServer
{
    private TcpListener listener;
    private bool serverIsRunning;

    public void Start()
    {
        this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        this.listener.Start();

        this.serverIsRunning = true;

        while (this.serverIsRunning)
        {
            if (!listener.Pending())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                continue;
            }

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            Thread session = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartNewClientSession));
            session.Start(client);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void StartNewClientSession(object data)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)data;

        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            // Get HTTP request from client
            byte[] receiveBuffer = null;

            if (clientStream.CanRead && clientStream != null)
            {
                receiveBuffer = NetworkManager.ReadMessage(clientStream);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

            string request = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer);

            Console.WriteLine(request);

            string[] splittedRequest = request.Split(new char[0]);

            string host = GetHostFromRequest(splittedRequest);

            if (host == string.Empty)
            {
                continue;
            }

            TcpClient server = new TcpClient(host, 80);

            NetworkStream serverStream = server.GetStream();

            // Forward HTTP request to server
            if (serverStream.CanWrite && serverStream != null)
            {
                NetworkManager.SendMessage(serverStream, receiveBuffer);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Get HTTP response from server
            if (serverStream.CanRead && serverStream != null)
            {
                receiveBuffer = NetworkManager.ReadMessage(serverStream);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }

            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer);

            Console.WriteLine(response);

            // Forward HTTP response to client
            if (clientStream.CanWrite && clientStream != null)
            {
                NetworkManager.SendMessage(clientStream, receiveBuffer);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetHostFromRequest(string[] request)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < request.Length; i++)
        {
            if (request[i] == "Host:")
            {
                string[] checkHost = request[i + 1].Split(':');

                if (checkHost.Length != 1)
                {
                    return checkHost[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    return request[i + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class NetworkManager
{
    public static byte[] ReadMessage(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[8192];

        if (stream.CanRead && stream != null)
        {
            int receivedBytes = stream.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);
        }

        return receiveBuffer;
    }

    public static void SendMessage(NetworkStream stream, byte[] sendBuffer)
    {
        if (stream.CanWrite && stream != null)
        {
            stream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It does not work right now" does not give us much to help with.

Comment: Sorry...I don't know what the exact problem is. I try to forward the http requests and responses, but I am not able to load a website.